# Covertly monitoring teen's iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, monitoring

My friend has an at-risk teen and the child's counselor as asked her to monitor his online activities without his knowledge.  Since I'm a "computer guy" she asked me for guidance.  But most of the solutions I'm finding are require jailbreaking his phone and I don't feel comfortable doing this (for a list of reasons).

Is there an Apple-supported way of installing covert tracking software on an iPhone in order to monitor a child's device?  I thought of doing this at the router instead, but of course SSL defeats a lot of this and routers won't catch 3G/4G traffic so I feel it has to be done on the device itself.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question poorly-phrased or unclear?

Comment: You basically asking to help you engage in criminal activity (in many countries of the world monitor somebody online activities without judge approval is criminal act). And even if it is not in yours it is still quite dubious.

Comment: I see.  So users of this community are rating the question based on their moral judgements, not based on its technical merits.  In the US, monitoring a child's phone is not illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up family sharing so you will have to give permission before any apps are downloaded.when using the same apple id for iCloud, the browser history from safari of the child will also be available for the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing the Prey ( https://preyproject.com/) which allows you to track the phone but this would involve installing the application on the target phone.

I don't think there is a Apple-supported way to monitor the online activities as such.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this pretty thoroughly, I think the only non-jailbreak method involves using iCloud (which is pretty good, though not foolproof).

You can buy all kinds of products that will parse your iCloud store from apple and give it to you in a nice format.  For $99.  Apple itself doesn't sell such a product, so you're left with buying sketchy software from China to do it. :(

My approach: I downloaded the hacker tool used in the iCloud breach from Summer 2014 and used that to access iCloud.  Of course, I did a hand-audit of this code before trusting it (it's in python, so easy to read).  I extended it a little to make it easier to use and make it look nicer, but the guts are the same... you just need the iCloud acct name and password.

Anything else, you need a jailbreak.  The iOS 8 jailbreak is currently ill-understood by the community and seems quite risky to use.  Plus all the other bad things that go along with a jailbreak.

Comment: Hi! If this is your answer, please select it.